# Subquery SQL exec return null

Tags: sql, filter, subquery, ignite

Init table:

```
CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC".testtable 
( 
    id   INTEGER primary key, 
    name VARCHAR 
)

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1, 'test');
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (2, 'test2');
```

Query produces an error?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT id, name 
     FROM
         (SELECT id, name 
          FROM testtable)
    )
```

Running this query returns this error:

> [Code: 1, SQL State: 50000]
> class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null

[image]

exec normal,such as :

```
 select * from (
     select id,name from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )
     )

select * from (
     select * from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )  parent where id>1
     )

select * from (
     select id,name from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )  parent where id>1
     )
```

Comment: apache ignite 2.14.0 and 2.15.0 can't exec multi sub-query sql,such as: select * from (
     select id,name from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )
     )

select * from (
     select * from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )  parent where id>1
     )

select * from (
     select id,name from 
     (select id,name from testtable
     )  parent where id>1
     )

Answer (score 1):

You can using alias

select * from (
select id,name from (
select id,name from testtable
) as t
)as b

Comment: Running this query returns this error:

[Code: 1, SQL State: 50000]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null